# The gem Translations to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I working on translations features. I was researching but I still can't find a gem to support it. Can you recommend a gem for translations to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globalize builds on the I18n API in Ruby on Rails to add model translations to ActiveRecord models.

More information: https://github.com/globalize/globalize